# Python - Variable inside a variables name?

Tags: python, exec

I'm not sure if this is already on here, if so I'm sorry.

I am trying to put the output of a variable, a string in this case into another variables "name" if its called that, but using `exec` is not ideal and I don't want to put it all into an exec function.

Is there any way to do what I am attempting to do in this code?

```
world = world[(x,y)].type 
exec("if blocks." + world + ".hasUp == True:")
    tick(taX,taY)
```

Comment: Very unclear, but if I understand what you are trying to do, don't use `exec` but [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). (rule of thumb: **never** use `exec` or `eval`)

Comment: A variable has no output. Can you please rephrase your question, and make it clear what are the variables and what you mean by putting the output of a variable int another variable's "name"?

Comment: Could you please explain this in more detail?

Comment: This is an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) – you are trying to work around some unknown problem and now you ask if we can fix that bad workaround. Please add more of your code.

Comment: in addition to what usr2564301 said, it looks you trying to create variable/property dynamically and it hints at bad design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `__dict__`:

```
>>> def foo():
...     pass
... 
>>> a = "hello"
>>> foo.__dict__[a] = "world"
>>> foo.hello
'world'
```

`globals()` for a global variable (returns a dictionary of global variables):

```
>>> name = "may"
>>> globals()[name] = "the force be with you"
>>> may
'the force be with you'
```

`locals()` for a local variable:

```
>>> name = "life"
>>> locals()[name] = "was like a box of chocolates"
>>> life
'was like a box of chocolates'
```